# idea for Enable/disable add, edit, delete image button on obout grid?

Tags: c#, obout

how to Enable/disable OBOUT Grid Add, Edit, Delete image icon using C# or Jquery

i tried this code:

```
grdadmin.AllowAddingRecords = false;

protected void Grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataControlFieldCell cell = e.Row.Cells[10] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        Control linksContainer = cell.Controls[0].Controls[0];

        bool disableEdit = false;
        bool disableDelete = false;
        disableEdit = true;
        disableDelete = true;
        linksContainer.Controls[0].Visible = !disableEdit;
        linksContainer.Controls[2].Visible = !disableDelete;
        linksContainer.Controls[1].Visible = !disableEdit && !disableDelete;
    }
```

but i'm unable to  disable the icon

Answer (score 0):

```
rdadmin.AllowAddingRecords = false;

protected void Grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataControlFieldCell cell = e.Row.Cells[10] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
    Control linksContainer = cell.Controls[0].Controls[0];

    bool disableEdit = false;
    bool disableDelete = false;
    disableEdit = true;
    disableDelete = true;
    linksContainer.Controls[0].Enabled = !disableEdit;
    linksContainer.Controls[2].Enabled = !disableDelete;
    linksContainer.Controls[1].Enabled = !disableEdit && !disableDelete;
}
```

You must use Enabled to set.